# Rails 3 - Cant Install a git plugin through console...... How Can I Install A Plugin Manually

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins

I'm trying to install a plugin from the git repo =>  https://github.com/maccman/acts_as_recommendable   .

This is weird but I ran all kinds of things to install it =>

```
 rails plugin install https://github.com/maccman/acts_as_recommendable.git -force
 rails plugin install git://github.com/maccman/acts_as_recommendable.git --force
 rails plugin install https://github.com/maccman/acts_as_recommendable.git/ --force
 rails plugin install https://github.com/maccman/acts-as-recommendable.git --force
```

but the console doesnt show any files being added..... The vendor/plugins/ folder has an acts_as_recommendable nothing in it.

So I thought why not just try to download all the files and install them manually?

My question is where should I place the files?  So...

=> There is a /lib folder with the plugins main logic files (acts_as_recommendable.rb, cache_fix.rb, optimization.rb, progress_bar.rb)

=> a /tasks folder with a rake file called (acts_as_recommendable_tasks.rake)

=> a /test folder with all the basic testing files

=> a rake file

and => a file called init.rb which has the 'requires' for the rb's in the /lib folder.

Where do I put all these?

should I throw all of them in the /vendor/plugins/acts_as_recommendable/ folder?

or add the files in the /lib to the main rails /lib folder, etc (but where does the init.rb file go?)

Has anyone tried installing these files manually and using the plugins this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a quick glance it **may** be that the plugin is not Rails 3 compatible - see https://github.com/maccman/acts_as_recommendable/commit/03a99454431cd09f8b5b755fcf04b3838eda80e0

http://railsplugins.org/ is a good source for compatible Rails 3 plugins.

Comment: Sadly it hasn't been updated yet.... Is there any to install the files manually an check if it works?

Comment: The code would need to be updated to support the new Rails 3 plugin architecture. This explains it quite nicely - http://boldr.net/upgrade-plugins-gems-rails-3.

Comment: You could then install locally using bundler: gem "acts_as_recommendable", :path => "../acts_as_recommendable"

Answer (score 1):

Just put the files in vendor/plugins/acts_as_recommendable. Some plugins have an install.rb file which gets run on install to add other files to the project or whatever, but that plugin does not, so all you need to do is add the files to vendor/plugins.